# Homogeneous equation of order $2$

Tags: calculus

I have $4a\ddot{z}+gz=0$ and I must find the the solution for this equation.

I use $z=x$ and now i will have $4ax^2+gx=0$ and I will resolve normal as a quadric equation to find solution and in the end I will put the solution in $a*\sin(x_1)+b*\cos(x_2)$ because the first equation is a homogeneous equation of order $2$. But I really don't get it how to find two solution from that. i must have +$\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}$ and -$\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}$

Answer (score 0):

You have a differential equation, not an algebraic equation. Then, $\displaystyle{\pm\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}}$ does not work.

---

We can look for solutions of the form $z=Ce^{\lambda t}$, where $C$ and $\lambda$ are constants. Then 
\begin{align*}
\dot{z}&=C\lambda e^{\lambda t}\\
\ddot{z}&=C\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}\\
\end{align*}
And so $4a\ddot{z}+gz=0 \iff C(4a\lambda^2+g)e^{\lambda t}=0\iff 4a\lambda^2+g=0$.
If $a$ and $g$ are real positive constants we have
$$\lambda=\pm i\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}\qquad\text{where }i^2=-1$$ 
Then, there are two solutions of the type $z=Ce^{\lambda t}$: $z_1=C_1e^{iwt}$ and $z_2=C_2e^{-iwt}$ where $w=\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}$.
By Euler's identity we have
\begin{align*}
z_1&=C_1(\cos wt+i\sin wt)\qquad\text{and setting }C_1=\alpha_1+i\beta_1\text{ we get}\\
z_1&=(\alpha_1+i\beta_1)(\cos wt+i\sin wt)\\
z_1&=(\alpha_1\cos wt-\beta_1\sin wt)+i(\alpha_1\sin wt+\beta_1\cos wt)
\end{align*}
In an similar way, we can write $C_2=\alpha_2+i\beta_2$ and
$$z_2=(\alpha_2\cos wt-\beta_2\sin wt)+i(\alpha_2\sin wt+\beta_2\cos wt)$$
It is not hard to proof that $k_1z_1+k_2z_2$ is also a solution, taking real part of this and setting $c_1=k_1\alpha_2+\alpha_2$, $c_2=-k_1\beta_1-k_2\beta_2$ we get the solution
$$\color{blue}{z=c_1\cos\left(wt\right)+c_2\sin\left(wt\right),\qquad\qquad w= \sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}}$$

Comment: I am sorry about that, it was -i$\sqrt{\frac{g}{4a}}$